# Greasemonkey script to auto fill the values of a form on a specified page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created a Greasemonkey script to allow me to quickly fill a specific form on a specific URL, for testing/dev purposes. If the current URL matches any of the urls found in the `formsDefault` array a button is added to the page that allows the user to auto fill with the default values.

This is my first time using arrow functions in JS.

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

(function($) {
    'use strict';

    var formDefaults = [
        {
            urlPattern : '/profile/user',
            valueSet : [
                { selector : '#username', value : 'bill' },
                { selector : '#lastname', value : 'miller' },
                { selector : '#auth_pin', value : '1234' },
            ]
        },
        {
            urlPattern : '/profile/company',
            valueSet : [
                { selector : '#companyname', value : 'bill' },
                { selector : '#state', value : 'washington' },
            ]
        },
    ];

    var formFiller = {
        valueSet : null,

        run(formDefaults) {
            var valueSetObj = this.tryEachPattern(this);
            if (valueSetObj !== null) {
                this.valueSet = valueSetObj.valueSet;
                this.showFormFillButton(this);
            }
        },

        tryEachPattern : (_this) => {
            var valueSetObj = null;
            for (var i = formDefaults.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                valueSetObj = formDefaults[i];
                var matched = _this.matchUrl(_this, valueSetObj.urlPattern);
                if (matched === true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return valueSetObj;
        },

        matchUrl : (_this, urlPattern) => {
            var matched = !!location.href.match(urlPattern);
            return matched;
        },

        fillForm : (_this) => {
            var valueSet = _this.valueSet;
            for (var i = valueSet.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var value = valueSet[i];
                $(value.selector).val(value.value);
            }
        },

        showFormFillButton : (_this) => {
            var button = $('<button type="button" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 10px">Auto Fill</button>');
            button.on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                _this.fillForm(_this);
            });
            $('body').append(button);
        },
    };

    // Ready, set, go
    formFiller.run(formDefaults);

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your code is generally easy to read and understand, I believe you have slightly over complicated things, there's no need to define an object with several methods to autocomplete a form.

Before I get to that though, let's take a look at your code.

1. Good work with encapsulating all of your code in an IIFE and forcing strict mode.
2. `formDefaults` is a decent name, I was able to guess almost exactly what it would contain when I first read it. However, since it also contains the page url, I would rename this to `pages`. `urlPattern` is also decent, though I expected it to be a regex due to the `pattern` suffix. `valueSet` on the other hand gives me absolutely no information about what it contains. I'd recommend renaming this to something like `defaults`.
3. The `run` method accepts a `formDefaults` parameter, but doesn't use it. It calls `tryEachPattern` and `tryEachPattern` uses the variable declared outside `formFiller`. If you take parameters, you should use them.
4. Using arrow functions doesn't actually help you here. Every single arrow function in this code takes a `_this` parameter. Arrow functions are supposed to make working with `this` easier, not more cumbersome! Just use regular functions if you need to pass a `_this` argument.
5. `tryEachPattern` is more complex than it needs to be. There is an [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method which can find a match in an array for you and returns `undefined` if the value was not found.
6. Don't explicitly compare boolean values with `===`, in `tryEachPattern` you can just do `if (matched)` which is easier to read.
7. Don't assign a result to a variable just to return that variable. `var matched = ...; return matched` can just be written as `return ...`.
8. Don't use `String.match` to test if a string contains another string. Use [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).
9. Prefer `const` and `let` to `var`. `const` is especially helpful as it tells readers that the assigned value will not be changed (though it could be mutated).
10. In `fillForm`, there's no need to write a bounded `for` loop. Prefer [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) pattern or the [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) call to make it easier to immediately know you are looping over everything.
11. I don't see any reason that the `click` handler should call `event.preventDefault()`, the button won't cause any navigation so it shouldn't be necessary unless the page does something odd.
12. If the page is already including jQuery, it makes sense to use it here as it simplifies the creation of the auto fill button. Otherwise, it only takes like 4 more lines of code and I would recommend dropping the jQuery dependency to speed up your script.
13. jQuery provides a [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method as a shorter alternative to `.on('click', ...`
14. [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is an amazing tool that can make code easier to read by giving immediate access to desired properties on an object.

At the start I mentioned that this was more complicated than it needed to be. Here is how I would write an equivalent script.

```js
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    const pages = [
        {
            url: '/profile/user',
            defaults: [
                { selector: '#username', value: 'bill' },
                { selector: '#lastname', value: 'miller' },
                { selector: '#auth_pin', value: '1234' },
            ]
        },
        {
            url: '/profile/company',
            defaults: [
                { selector: '#companyname', value: 'bill' },
                { selector: '#state', value: 'washington' },
            ]
        },
    ];

    const page = pages.find(({ url }) => location.href.includes(url));

    if (page) {
        const button = $('<button type="button" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 10px">Auto Fill</button>');
        button.click(() => {
            for (const { selector, value } of page.defaults) {
                $(selector).val(value);
            }
        });
        $('body').append(button);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: In "2" of your numbered list, you mention that the name urlPattern implies that it is a regular expression. It was meant to allow regular expressions. Can you update your example to allow regular expression matching with the find function? Also, thank you!!!

Comment: @CoryBaumer in that case just change `includes` back to `match`, no other changes are needed :)